# hasMany relationship emberjs. Promise seems to fulfill but no content

Tags: ember.js

Hi as per [Relationship document](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_relationships) Comments for a post can be loaded by post.get('comments'). I am tryin to acheive same my promise gets fullfilled but content is empty

Here are my attempts with

[With Mockjax](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/anoFaSef/10/edit)
[With Fixtures](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/anoFaSef/12/edit)

I tried loading Fixtures to
    store directly with this guys help [endash2](http://amalgamated.io/emberjs-and-fixtures/)

My PostsPostRoute

```
App.PostsPostRoute = Em.Route.extend({

     setupController: function(controller, model){ 
         console.log(model.get('tags')); //problem
         controller.set('content', model);
     } 
});
```

post model

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body:DS.attr('string'),
  tags: DS.hasMany('Tag',{async: true})
});
```

tag data

```
$.mockjax({
    url: '/tags',
    responseTime: 100,
    responseText: { 
        tags: [
            {id: 1, name: 'Apple', post_ids: [2]},
            {id: 2, name: 'iOS', post_ids: [2]},
            {id: 3, name: 'Open Source', post_ids: [1,3]},
            {id: 4, name: 'Drama', post_ids: [1]},
            {id: 5, name: 'Router', post_ids: [3]},
            {id: 6, name: 'Ember', post_ids: [3]}
        ]
    }
});
```

post data

```
$.mockjax({
    url: '/posts',
    responseTime: 100,
    responseText: { 
        posts: [
            {
                id: 1,
                title: 'Open Source, Thick Skin',
                body: 'Yesterday, Heather Arthur posted a well-written and sad account of how she felt after the open ridicule of one of the projects she had made available on GitHub. This caused the battle lines to be lain between the Ruby and node.js communities. Friends of mine opened fire at one another. That made me sad.',
                author_id: 1,
                comment_ids: [1, 2, 3, 6],
                tag_ids: [3,4]
            }  ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial is for an older Ember Data.  You'll want to read the transition document for Ember Data 1.0 beta + https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md .

That being said here's some points to note:

You no longer define the store, just adapters:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter;
```

hasMany and belongsTo types should be camel case

```
tags: DS.hasMany('tag', {async: true})
```

the json relationships shouldn't have _ids

```
       {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Open Source, Thick Skin',
            body: 'Yesterday, Heather Arthur posted a well-written and sad account of how she felt after the open ridicule of one of the projects she had made available on GitHub. This caused the battle lines to be lain between the Ruby and node.js communities. Friends of mine opened fire at one another. That made me sad.',
            author: 1,
            comments: [1, 2, 3, 6],
            tags: [1]
        }
```

findMany will use the data property when making the ajax (this is for tags: [1] )

```
$.mockjax({
    url: '/tags',
    data: { ids: [1] },
    responseTime: 100,
    responseText: {
        tags: [
          {id: 1, name: 'Apple', posts: [2]}
          ]
    }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/anoFaSef/14/edit